# How to calculate the result of this repeating additions quickly

Tags: pattern-recognition

We're given an exercise for a programming lesson. It goes like this:

Starts with an array, ranging from $1$ to $n$. At every iteration, add $2$ neighboring numbers together. Stop when the amount of numbers in the array reaches $1$.

Here's a visual representation:

```
1  2  3  4  5
 \/ \/ \/ \/
 3  5  7  9
  \/ \/ \/
  8  12 16
   \/  \/
   20  28
    \  /
     48
```

The problem is, doing this step by step took way too much time, especially when we have to deal with $n = 2018201820182018$. So, is there a way to calculate the final number without doing the addition?

EDIT: We're allowed to do a modulus of the answer with $10^9$, and I've found a formula for calculating the final number: $(n+1) * 2^{(n-2)}$, but the latter part still gives a very large result. Are there any other formulas?

Comment: What if you put variables, $a_1,\ldots,a_5$ in that example in place of $1,\ldots,5$?

Comment: what do you mean? i don't quite understand it, sorry

Comment: The good thing about modulus is that it behaves well under addition and multiplication. You can try iteratively multiplying by 2 and taking the modulus instead of calculating the immensely large power and then taking the modulus.

Comment: I believe there is no need for another formula, $(n+1) \cdot 2^{n-2}$ is simple enough. To compute it in reasonable time, use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring, and to avoid dealing with large numbers, apply modulo $10^9$ to intermediate results.

Comment: Thanks, will try it out later.

Comment: It works, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is more like a long comment than an answer.

If you take Lord Shark's advice and set $a_1=1$, $a_2=2$, $a_3=3$, $a_4=4$, and $a_5=5$, and then express every other number in your example in terms of $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$, $a_4$, and $a_5$, an interesting and familiar pattern emerges.

We start out pretty simply:
\begin{align}
3&=a_1+a_2 \\
5&=a_2+a_3 \\
7&=a_3+a_4 \\
9&=a_4+a_5
\end{align}
The next step is where we start to see the pattern:
\begin{align}
8&=(a_1+a_2)+(a_2+a_3)=\color{red}1a_1+\color{red}2a_2+\color{red}1a_3 \\
12&=(a_2+a_3)+(a_3+a_4)=\color{red}1a_2+\color{red}2a_3+\color{red}1a_4 \\
16&=(a_3+a_4)+(a_4+a_5)=\color{red}1a_3+\color{red}2a_4+\color{red}1a_5
\end{align}
And it becomes even clearer in the last two steps:
\begin{align}
20&=(a_1+2a_2+a_3)+(a_2+2a_3+a_4)=\color{red}1a_1+\color{red}3a_2+\color{red}3a_3+\color{red}1a_4 \\
28&=(a_2+2a_3+a_4)+(a_3+2a_4+a_5)=\color{red}1a_2+\color{red}3a_3+\color{red}3a_4+\color{red}1a_5
\end{align}
\begin{align}
48=(a_1+3a_2+3a_3+a_4)+(a_2+3a_3+3a_4+a_5)=\color{red}1a_1+\color{red}4a_2+\color{red}6a_3+\color{red}4a_4+\color{red}1a_5
\end{align}
See those coefficients? I think the binomial theorem might come in handy.

Comment: Yeah I also noticed the similarity between this and Pascal's triangle, maybe I'll try it when my own formula doesn't work.